# Jacobson Radical and Finite Dimensional Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In general, it is usually not the case that for a ring $R$, the Jacobson radical of $R$ has to be equal to the intersection of the maximal ideals of $R$.

However, what I do like to know is, if we are given a finite-dimensional algebra $A$ over the field $F$, is it true that the Jacobson radical of $A$ is precisely the intersection of the maximal ideals of $A$?

Comment: Yes, although you need to say "left maximal ideals" or "right maximal ideals" to make the statement accurate, since finite dimensional algebras over $F$ of course will in general not be commutative.  I believe that, in general, so long as your ring has a 1, then this will be true.

Comment: shouldn't it be the case that the Jacobson radical is contained in the intersection of maximal (two-sided) ideals instead?

Comment: @rschwieb You're right, of course. In the general case it's not true that the intersection of the maximal ideals is contained in the Jacobson radical.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably familiar with the basic result that among Artinian rings, the semiprime rings (intersection of all prime ideals $P(R)$ is zero) and semiprimitive rings (intersection of all maximal right ideals $J(R)$ is zero) coincide. These are precisely semisimple rings. So, it makes sense that they should coincide for Artinian rings. By the same basic facts, the prime ideals of Artinian rings coincide with the maximal ideals, so that justifies us using $P(R)$ above as notation for the intersection of maximal ideals.

Here's an easy way to see they coincide for a finite dimensional algebra $R$:

Since $P(R)$ is a nil ideal and $R$ is Artinian, $P(R)$ is nilpotent, and hence is contained inside $J(R)$. Since $R/P(R)$ is semisimple, and $J(R)$ is minimal among ideals which make a semisimple quotient of $R$,  $J(R)\subseteq P(R)$. Thus, the two sets are equal.

---

Denoting the intersection of maximal ideals as $M(R)$, there's an easy way to see why $J(R)\subseteq M(R)$ for all rings. If $I$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, then $I+J(R)$ is also an ideal, but it cannot be $R$. Thus $I+J(R)=I$ implies $J(R)\subseteq I$. Taking the intersection over all $I$, $J(R)\subseteq M(R)$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is true. See

J.A. Drozd, V.V. Kirichenko, 
Finite dimensional algebras, 
Springer, 1994

Comment: You might at least give a chapter number... The book has a considerable number of results! :-)

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: I have Russian version and I am not sure that chapter numbers coinside. In my book this is chapt.3, sec.1.